Exported glTF file looks not as expected
I've been building a 3D model of a burning meteorite with smoke to add it to my simple Three.js web shooting game.

I am pretty much happy with the look of my meteorite.
When I tried to export it as a glTF file and loaded it into my Three.js project, my meteorites looked not as expected. The smoke domain (space surrounding the meteorite) looks not transparent and thus the meteorites are not to be seen. I'd like the exported object to look similar as in my first screenshot.

I tried to find the solution on my own, but couldn't come up with anything helpful :(
Maybe you have some ideas/tips on how to fix it?

Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315166/volume-type-to-gltf2-0-issue Also have you checked how three.js supports volumetrics?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

@Lauloque & Duarte Farrajota Ramos  thank you a lot for your suggetions. I am not sure it has to do with this specific format type (gltf) or volumetrics suppport in Three.js. I tred to export my object in several other formats and view them with online tool - the outcome is the same the surronding of the meteorit is not transparent, so I get a huge grey parallelepiped instead of my meteorit.
I guess the problem is in some modell setting...

In Blender, that box is your simulation domain and its volumetric material allows you to see the volumetric data simulated inside. If you don't export volumetrics correctly plus with the right material, or if you don't import and use that correctly in your target software, it will look like a box.
